# Css animating an imaginary creature chasing a figure

Tags: css

Using CSS, I am trying to animate an imaginary creature chasing a figure in a maze without going through the maze walls. The imaginary creature should almost catch the figure at the end. The chasing starts at the initial position where they are currently positioning and ends at the exit. The maze layout is on the fiddle link. I am need some assistance to figure out the animation. My keyframe is not working correctly ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suabiut/zt24cjfp/2/))

```css
svg#figure {
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 2;
fill: red; 
stroke: black; 

/*    animation*/

animation-name: testfigure;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction:normal;
}

svg#monster {
fill: red;
fill-opacity: 0.5;
height: 40px;
width: 80px;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: -100px;
z-index: 3;

/*animation*/
animation-name: testmonster;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-iteration-count: 2;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-delay: -3s;
}



@keyframes testmonster {
0%   {background-color:red; left:38px;}
25%  {background-color:yellow; left:38px; top:0px;}
50%  {background-color:blue; left:100px; top:200px;}
75%  {background-color:green; left:80px; left:200px;}
100% {background-color:red; left:50px; top:100px;}
}




@keyframes testfigure {
0%   {background-color:red; left:38px;}
25%  {background-color:yellow; left:38px;top:0px;}
50%  {background-color:blue; left:35px; top:100px;}
/*75%  {background-color:green; top:50px; left:200px;}*/
/*100% {background-color:red; top:50px; top:50px;}*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an adjustment to my CSS to fix it. There is probably a better way to do that though.

```css
svg#figure {
                height: 40px;
                width: 40px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 0px;
                z-index: 2;
                fill: red; 
                stroke: black; 

            /*    animation*/

                animation-name: testfigure;
                animation-duration: 15s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-direction:normal;
            }

            svg#monster {
                fill: red;
                fill-opacity: 0.5;
                height: 40px;
                width: 80px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: -100px;
                z-index: 3;

                /*animation*/
                animation-name: testmonster;
                animation-duration: 15s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-direction: normal;
                animation-delay: 1s;
            }



            @keyframes testmonster {
                0%   {margin-left:120px}
                15%  {margin-top: -70px;}
                30%  {margin-left: 190px;}
                35%  {margin-top: 60px;}
                45%  {margin-left: 100px;margin-top:130px;}
                50%  {margin-left: 250px;}
                70%  {margin-top: -50px;}
                80% {margin-left: 310px;}
                100% {margin-top: 250px;margin-left: 0px;}
            }




            @keyframes testfigure {
                0%   {margin-left:38px}
                15%  {margin-top: -80px;}
                30%  {margin-left: 100px;}
                35%  {margin-top: 65px;}
                45%  {margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 130px;}
                50%  {margin-left: 165px;}
                70%  {margin-top: -50px;}
                80% {margin-left: 230px;}
                100% {margin-top: 250px;margin-left: 0px;}




            }
```